# How to add a field in a yaml file after a specific key in yaml

Tags: yaml, yq

Hello I have multiple yaml files which I need to updated, and to each file I need to add one or two lines after imagename line. I want use yq, but I am able only to add new value at end of yaml file

My file

```
containers:
  container1:
    name: service
    org: "company:"
    imagename: thirdparty-ingestion-service
    tagprefix: "-"
    tag: 772x0-69
    ports:
      - port: 6066
        name: debug
      - port: 11100
```

How it should look

```
containers:
  container1:
    name: service
    org: "company:"
    imagename: thirdparty-ingestion-service
    imageprefix: ""
    tagprefix: "-"
    tag: 72x0-69
    ports:
      - port: 6066
        name: debug
      - port: 11100
```

How I added so far

```
yq .containers.container1.imageprefix="" values.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

While items of an array do have an order, fields within objects do not, so inserting a new field at the desired position may very well not be respected by the next application processing the resulting data. That said, for the time being, collecting the fields (and their values) into an array, modifying their order, then re-assembling the object, will do the job. However, different trickery is needed depending on [which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of yq you want to use.

Using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```bash
.containers.container1 |= with_entries(
  ., (select(.key == "imagename") | {key: "imageprefix", value: ""})
)
```

Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```bash
.containers.container1 |= (
  to_entries
  | (.[] | select(.key == "imagename") | key + 1) as $i
  | .[:$i] + [{"key": "imageprefix", "value": ""}] + .[$i:]
  | from_entries
)
```

Comment: When I make one line command from above then I am get some error `yq .containers.container1 |= (  to_entries  | (.[] | select(.key == "imagename") | key + 1) as $i  | .[:$i] + [{"key": "imageprefix", "value": ""}] + .[$i:]  | from_entries) values.yaml`
as was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @majan **Always** enclose the filter with (single) quotes: `yq '…' file.yaml` (and make sure you're using the right approach wrt your implementation of yq),

Comment: under linux it work under windows no, but at least on linux is working :)

Comment: @majan Windows has special quoting rules. If you are using Powershell, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) might help.